# Which concurrent Queue implementation should I use in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue

From the JavaDocs:

- A [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) is an appropriate choice when many threads will share access to a common collection. This queue does not permit null elements.
- [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) is a classic "bounded buffer", in which a fixed-sized array holds elements inserted by producers and extracted by consumers. This class supports an optional fairness policy for ordering waiting producer and consumer threads
- [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) typically have higher throughput than array-based queues but less predictable performance in most concurrent applications.

I have 2 scenarios, one requires the queue to support many producers (threads using it) with one consumer and the other is the other way around.

I do not understand which implementation to use. Can somebody explain what the differences are?

Also, what is the 'optional fairness policy' in the `ArrayBlockingQueue`?

Comment: You forgot to ask about PriorityBlockingQueue also, which is useful for specifying an order in which threads get processed.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Basically the difference between them are performance characteristics and blocking behavior.

Taking the easiest first, `ArrayBlockingQueue` is a queue of a fixed size. So if you set the size at 10, and attempt to insert an 11th element, the insert statement will block until another thread removes an element. The fairness issue is what happens if multiple threads try to insert and remove at the same time (in other words during the period when the Queue was blocked). A fairness algorithm ensures that the first thread that asks is the first thread that gets. Otherwise, a given thread may wait longer than other threads, causing unpredictable behavior (sometimes one thread will just take several seconds because other threads that started later got processed first). The trade-off is that it takes overhead to manage the fairness, slowing down the throughput.

The most important difference between `LinkedBlockingQueue` and `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is that if you request an element from a `LinkedBlockingQueue` and the queue is empty, your thread will wait until there is something there. A `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` will return right away with the behavior of an empty queue.

Which one depends on if you need the blocking. Where you have many producers and one consumer, it sounds like it. On the other hand, where you have many consumers and only one producer, you may not need the blocking behavior, and may be happy to just have the consumers check if the queue is empty and move on if it is.

Comment: Answer is misleading. Both LinkedBlockingQueue and ConcurrentLinkedQueue has method "poll()" which removes head of queue or returns null (does not block) and method "offer(E e)" which inserts in to tail of queue and does not block. The difference is that only LinkedBlockingQueue has blocking operations *in addition* to the non-blocking operations - and for that privilege, you pay the price that LinkedBlockingQueue actually has some locking. The other answer explains this.

Answer (score 135):

[ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) means no locks are taken (i.e. no synchronized(this) or [Lock.lock](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#lock()) calls).  It will use a [CAS - Compare and Swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) operation during modifications to see if the head/tail node is still the same as when it started.  If so, the operation succeeds.  If the head/tail node is different, it will spin around and try again.

[LinkedBlockingQueue](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) will take a lock before any modification.  So your offer calls would block until they get the lock.  You can use the offer overload that takes a TimeUnit to say you are only willing to wait X amount of time before abandoning the add (usually good for message type queues where the message is stale after X number of milliseconds).

Fairness means that the Lock implementation will keep the threads ordered.  Meaning if Thread A enters and then Thread B enters, Thread A will get the lock first.  With no fairness, it is undefined really what happens.  It will most likely be the next thread that gets scheduled.

As for which one to use, it depends.  I tend to use [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) because the time it takes my producers to get work to put onto the queue is diverse.  I don't have a lot of producers producing at the exact same moment.  But the consumer side is more complicated because poll won't go into a nice sleep state.  You have to handle that yourself.

Comment: And under what conditions ArrayBlockingQueue is better than LinkedBlockingQueue?

Comment: @akapelko  ArrayBlockingQueue allows for more fine-grained ordering.

Comment: What doest it mean - " it will spin around and try again." ?

Answer (score 9):

Your question title mentions Blocking Queues.  However, `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is **not** a blocking queue.

The [`BlockingQueue`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)s are `ArrayBlockingQueue`, `DelayQueue`, `LinkedBlockingDeque`, `LinkedBlockingQueue`, `PriorityBlockingQueue`, and `SynchronousQueue`.

Some of these are clearly not fit for your purpose (`DelayQueue`, `PriorityBlockingQueue`, and `SynchronousQueue`).  `LinkedBlockingQueue` and `LinkedBlockingDeque` are identical, except that the latter is a double-ended Queue (it implements the Deque interface).

Since `ArrayBlockingQueue` is only useful if you want to limit the number of elements, I'd stick to `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

Comment: I removed the Blocking word from the title, thanks.
Let me see if I got it, what you said means that LinkedBlockingQueue can be used in multile consumers/produces scenarios over the same object ?

Comment: I thought that ArrayBlockingQueue allows for more fine-grained ordering of threads?  Hence its advantage.

Answer (score 4):

ArrayBlockingQueue has lower memory footprint, it can reuse element node, not like LinkedBlockingQueue that have to create a LinkedBlockingQueue$Node object for each new insertion.

Comment: good point! i prefer ArrayBlockingQueue more than LinkedBlockingQueue

Comment: This is not necessarily true - if your queue is close to empty a lot of the time but needs to be able to grow large, the `ArrayBlockingQueue` will have a much worse memory footprint - it still has a large array allocated in memory the whole time, while the `LinkedBlockingQueue` will have a negligible memory footprint when close to empty.

Answer (score 1):

1. `SynchronousQueue` ( Taken from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591610/when-should-i-use-synchronousqueue) )

`SynchronousQueue` is more of a handoff, whereas the `LinkedBlockingQueue` just allows a single element. The difference being that the `put()` call to a `SynchronousQueue` will not return until there is a corresponding `take()` call, but with a `LinkedBlockingQueue` of size 1, the `put()` call (to an empty queue) will return immediately. It's essentially the `BlockingQueue` implementation for when you don't really want a queue (you don't want to maintain any pending data).

2. `LinkedBlockingQueue` (`LinkedList` Implementation but Not Exactly JDK Implementation of `LinkedList` It uses static inner class Node to maintain Links between elements )

Constructor for LinkedBlockingQueue

```
public LinkedBlockingQueue(int capacity) 
{
        if (capacity < = 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.capacity = capacity;
        last = head = new Node< E >(null);   // Maintains a underlying linkedlist. ( Use when size is not known )
}
```

Node class Used to Maintain Links

```
static class Node<E> {
    E item;
    Node<E> next;
    Node(E x) { item = x; }
}
```

3 . ArrayBlockingQueue ( Array Implementation )

Constructor for ArrayBlockingQueue

```
public ArrayBlockingQueue(int capacity, boolean fair) 
{
            if (capacity < = 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            this.items = new Object[capacity]; // Maintains a underlying array
            lock = new ReentrantLock(fair);
            notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
            notFull =  lock.newCondition();
}
```

IMHO Biggest Difference between `ArrayBlockingQueue` and `LinkedBlockingQueue` is clear from constructor one has **underlying data structure Array and other linkedList**.

`ArrayBlockingQueue` uses [single-lock double condition algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015571/arrayblockingqueue-uses-a-single-lock-for-insertion-and-removal-but-linkedblocki) and `LinkedBlockingQueue` is variant of the "two lock queue" algorithm and it has 2 locks 2 conditions ( takeLock , putLock)

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentLinkedQueue is lock-free, LinkedBlockingQueue is not. Every time you invoke LinkedBlockingQueue.put() or LinkedBlockingQueue.take(), you need acquire the lock first. In other word, LinkedBlockingQueue has poor concurrency. If you care performance, try ConcurrentLinkedQueue + LockSupport.