# Ordering of notify and wait in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to write a Producer Consumer code. Below is the original code I wrote.

```
Stack<Integer> buffer = new Stack<>();
volatile int i = 1;

class Consumer implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            synchronized (buffer) {
                System.out.println("Consumer taking lock : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                while(buffer.isEmpty()){
                    try{
                        System.out.println("Consumer releasing lock :" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        buffer.wait();
                        System.out.println("Consumer woken up :" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    } catch(InterruptedException ie){
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(buffer.pop());
                buffer.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            synchronized (buffer) {
                System.out.println("Producer taking lock : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                while(!buffer.isEmpty()){
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Producer going into wait set :" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        buffer.wait();
                        System.out.println("Producer woken up :" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                buffer.push(i);
                i++;
                buffer.notify();
            }
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ProducerConsumerUnitBuffer obj = new ProducerConsumerUnitBuffer();
    Thread producerThread1 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread1 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread2 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread2 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread3 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread3 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread4 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread4 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread5 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread5 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread6 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread6 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread7 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread7 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread8 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread8 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread9 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread9 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread10 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread10 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());

    producerThread1.start();
    consumerThread1.start();
    producerThread2.start();
    consumerThread2.start();
    producerThread3.start();
    consumerThread3.start();
    producerThread4.start();
    consumerThread4.start();
    producerThread5.start();
    consumerThread5.start();
    producerThread6.start();
    consumerThread6.start();
    producerThread7.start();
    consumerThread7.start();
    producerThread8.start();
    consumerThread8.start();
    producerThread9.start();
    consumerThread9.start();
    producerThread10.start();
    consumerThread10.start();

}
```

This code always stalls. Although the application doesn't terminate, it stops printing anything which means no thread is entering the synchronized block.

Although, when I use **notifyAll() instead of notify()** the code works perfectly fine.

**EDIT**

As per suggestions, I tried changing the code so that there are 2 separate objects for producers and consumers to take a lock on. Also, the producers notify() the consumers when an object is put in the buffer.

```
public class ProducerConsumerDifferentObjects {

Stack<Integer> buffer = new Stack<>();
Boolean producerLockingObject = Boolean.FALSE;
Boolean consumerLockingObject = Boolean.TRUE;
volatile int i = 1;

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (consumerLockingObject) {
                while (buffer.isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                        consumerLockingObject.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(buffer.pop());
                consumerLockingObject.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (producerLockingObject) {
                while (!buffer.isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                        producerLockingObject.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                buffer.push(i);
                i++;
                producerLockingObject.notify();
                synchronized (consumerLockingObject) {
                    consumerLockingObject.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ProducerConsumerDifferentObjects obj = new ProducerConsumerDifferentObjects();
    Thread producerThread1 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread1 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread2 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread2 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread3 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread3 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread4 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread4 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread5 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread5 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread6 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread6 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread7 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread7 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread8 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread8 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread9 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread9 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());
    Thread producerThread10 = new Thread(obj.new Consumer());
    Thread consumerThread10 = new Thread(obj.new Producer());

    producerThread1.start();
    consumerThread1.start();
    producerThread2.start();
    consumerThread2.start();
    producerThread3.start();
    consumerThread3.start();
    producerThread4.start();
    consumerThread4.start();
    producerThread5.start();
    consumerThread5.start();
    producerThread6.start();
    consumerThread6.start();
    producerThread7.start();
    consumerThread7.start();
    producerThread8.start();
    consumerThread8.start();
    producerThread9.start();
    consumerThread9.start();
    producerThread10.start();
    consumerThread10.start();
}
```

}

Comment: There are a lot of things you are doing incorrectly.  First, you should never call wait() and notify() together.  They are meant to communicate changes in a condition to different threads.  Also, you should not be calling Thread.sleep at all;  instead, use wait() to allow a different thread to notify() you that the state of `buffer` has changed.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html.

Comment: @VGR I made a change as per your comment and the java doc. I'm still reaching a stage where all the threads are in wait. My problem is with the part where the thread is invoking wait(). As soon as wait() is invoked the thread gets suspended and the lock is released, but without calling notify(), how are the other threads called onto resume execution? I have edited the question with the new code.

Comment: Much better.  I would avoid using the Stack class, since it does its own synchronization internally, which may interfere with your synchronization.  The [ArrayDeque class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) is a better choice, as it has many of the same methods and doesn’t do internal synchronization.  Also, your code is not truly thread-safe, because you release and re-acquire the synchronization monitor with each while-loop iteration;  put the while loop *inside* the synchronized block to fix this.

Comment: @VGR There's nothing inherently wrong with using the same signal to indicate two different conditions. It's pretty common to use a single signal to mean both "empty" and "full" for a queue, for example. (Arguably, "this object changed state" is a single condition of interest to both producers and consumers.) Really the only wrinkle is that you have to make sure to call `notifyAll` instead of `notify` if there's any chance of waking the "wrong thread".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I really want to avoid notifyAll() as it unnecessarily wakes up all the threads, whereas technically I just want 1 producer and 1 consumer thread to wake up, check the condition and accordingly proceed. I want to keep trying this with notify() only. :)

Comment: @Nishit Then you need to make sure that any thread that can possibly be waiting can service the condition. There are a lot of subtle minefields if you don't use two separate wait sets for signalling the two different states. (Your current edited code is broken. No lock prevents the state from changing after we decide not to wait. You need [multiple conditions associated with a single lock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18490902/721269)!)

Comment: @Nishit: The edited code is wrong, because you use different lock objects for consumer and producer (this is bad by itself), and now a consumer may notify **only** a consumer - the effect you are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

In the *multiple* producer/*multiple* consumer (MPMC) scenario you are trying to use **single** object (`buffer`) for notify **both** consumers and producers. This is why you got stalling eventually: instead of notifying a producer, one **consumer notifies another consumer**. (Or producers notifiers another producer).

Consider the following possible ordering of events:

1. Consumer 1 waits on an empty buffer.
2. Consumer 2 waits on the empty buffer.
3. Producer produces an element, and notifies consumer 1. Then the producer waits on non-empty buffer.
4. **Consumer 1** awakes, consumes the only element in the buffer, **notifies the consumer 2**, and waits on the empty buffer.
5. Consumer 2 awakes, but immediately waits because the buffer is empty.

So all consumers and producers are in a waiting state.

Having more consumers and/or producers doesn't help: it still possible to all of them to be in a waiting state.

---

Possible ways for resolve the problem:

1. Having **different objects** for notify consumers and producers. In Java, you may create two [Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) objects from the single lock, one condition for notify consumers, and another - for notify producers.
2. Additionally synchronize producers with themselves, and consumers with themselves. So at most single producer and single consumer may wait on the common object.

Both approaches eliminates possibility of consumer-consumer or producer-producer notification.

---

It could be that changing wait condition for producers from "the buffer is non-empty" to "the buffer is full" will help in case of buffer's capacity of 2 elements or more. consumer-consumer notification is still possible, but may be complete stalling would be avoided. But this would be very tricky.