# ArrayBlockingQueue use one lock

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, blockingqueue

I know there have been questions and discussions about this([ArrayBlockingQueue uses a single lock for insertion and removal but LinkedBlockingQueue uses 2 separate locks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015571/arrayblockingqueue-uses-a-single-lock-for-insertion-and-removal-but-linkedblocki))
and
([What is the reason to implement ArrayBlockingQueue with one lock on tail and head?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739951/what-is-the-reason-to-implement-arrayblockingqueue-with-one-lock-on-tail-and-hea)), but I still don't understand it.

There is an accepted answer in the link given above:

> ArrayBlockingQueue has to avoid overwriting entries so that it needs to know where the start and the end is. A LinkedBlockQueue doesn't need to know this as it lets the GC worry about cleaning up Nodes in the queue.

I don't quite understand, can someone explain it to me?

Then I tried to transform ABQ with two locks and ran throughput tests following the code in book `Java Concurrency in practice`, and it did prove that the double-locked version of ABQ has better throughput.

All code (including ABQ using double lock implementatio and test code from book `Java Concurrency in practice`) can be seen here:  https://pastebin.com/QpW9dsVc

Is there a bug in the ABQ code that uses the double lock implementation, If not, why not use double locks.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't explain anything. The answer by @Gray seems more like it.

Comment: But it still seems possible to use double locks @user207421