# Feed an array into threads

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I need to split an array into 5 parts (the last one would not be an equal part probably),and feed into threads for processing in parallel.
An attempt is as below:

```
int skip=arr.length/5;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i+=skip){
                int[] ssub;
                if(i+skip>=arr.length){
                    sub=new int[arr.length-1]
                }
                else
                {
                    sub=new int[skip+1];
                }
                System.arraycopy(arr,0,sub,0,sub.length);
                Thread t=new Runnable(barrier,sub){

                };
                t.start();
        }
```

Any suggestion to make it more functional and avoiding local arrays is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Well in terms of making well organized Threads. You should look into [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), Simple [youtube video on ExecutorService](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRdHvv7zW6M)

In terms of organizing the arrays you can either split them non-locally or can create a Queue for that look towards, [Java Queue implementations, which one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301691/java-queue-implementations-which-one)

These threads may work at different speeds so a Queue is recommended please look into them.