# Wait & Notify among different Classes method

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, wait, notify

Though my actual problem is bit different , solving the following problem will help me . 
 I have built a simple javafx application with scenebuilder . I would like to take input from user via a textField in my application and print that one in another class Say, class A. How can i make a thread, in class A, wait until my another guicontroller notify after getting value from user . I want to do this in a loop.

**To be precise**, How can i use wait and notify among  threads in  different classes ?

Please pardon me for my scrappy question . thnx in advance

**Edited:** My actual program is to build a chat messenger . Where i have a  thread that will , after having the input from user , will forward to recipient . User will give input in a textField which will be handled in a guicontroller.

I want my guiController to notify the Thread that is waiting for sending message.

How can i do that  ?

Comment: Classes don't wait. Threads wait. To have two threads coordinate via notify/wait, they need to share a monitor object. You can get better answers if you described your actual problem.

Comment: @Thilo extremely sorry for that one . please read the edited part one if you can understand my problem clearly now .

Comment: It sounds like your GuiController wants to add the message to a queue that the sending thread is consuming. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301691/java-queue-implementations-which-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could theoretically do it like this

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    List<String> messages = new LinkedList<>();
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            String message;
            synchronized (messages) {
                if (messages.isEmpty()) {
                    // empty message queue -> wait
                    try {
                        messages.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        // unknown cause of interrupt -> just try reading the messages anew
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                message = messages.remove(0);
            }
            System.out.println("sending message: " + message);

            try {
                // simulate delay
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    });
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();

    textField.setOnAction(evt -> {
        synchronized (messages) {
            // add new message to queue
            messages.add(textField.getText());

            // notify thread
            messages.notify();
        }
        textField.clear();
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(textField);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

However there are much easier ways to achieve this effect:

#### `BlockingQueue`

This class is designed for this exact scenario: a consumer waiting for a producer, if necessary.

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<String> messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    while (true) {
        String message;
        try {
            message = messages.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println("sending message: "+message);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }
});
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();

textField.setOnAction(evt -> {
    try {
        messages.put(textField.getText());
        textField.clear();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
    
});
```

#### Using a `ExecutorService`

This class simply allows you to post the task to send the info to a `ExecutorService` that takes care of scheduling and executing the task. You can simply submit one task per message.

```
private ExecutorService executor;

@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
}

@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    executor.shutdownNow();
    // TODO: handle unsent messages or replace with executor.shutdown()
}

private void postMessage(String message) {
    executor.submit(() -> {
        System.out.println("sending message: "+message);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextField textField = new TextField();

    textField.setOnAction(evt -> {
        postMessage(textField.getText());
        textField.clear();
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(textField);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Note that there are different executors available to adjust the scheduling and for using multiple threads.