# Fastest way to perform a non-thread safe optional operation in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue

For monitoring purposes I want to maintain a sliding window of operations and results. I have found a data structure to do this quickly but it is not thread-safe.  I also don’t care if I drop some data because overall the picture should still be ok, so what’s the fastest way to do this in Java that can scale to hundreds of threads?  Is a singleton semaphore with a time-out on tryAcquire the best way? Or would a single threaded executor service that discarded messages when the queue was full be faster

Comment: You can just use one of the many concurrent queue implementations in the jdk. E.g. `java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue` it is unbounded and threadsafe. But I am not entirely sure about the performance. Maybe also have a look at another question which is similar: [Which concurrent Queue implementation should I use in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301691/which-concurrent-queue-implementation-should-i-use-in-java)

Comment: Could you provide more details and an example? This is IMO far not enough to answer.

Comment: There’s a mismatch between your question’s title and body. Do you want a “non-thread safe” solution or a thread safe one?

Comment: The operation is non-thread safe so I want to do it in a thread safe way

Comment: There’s too little information about what you actually want to do.