# Java thread safe concurrent queue with unique elements

Tags: java, concurrency, queue, thread-safety

I need a data structure that should be a concurrent and unique queue. `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` will solve my problem but I need to add unique elements in the queue(FIFO). Do I have to combine both `Set` and `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [PriorityBlockingQueue](https://www.baeldung.com/java-priority-blocking-queue) ??

Also you can take a look at [Which concurrent Queue implementation should I use in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301691/which-concurrent-queue-implementation-should-i-use-in-java)