# concurrent queue - general question (description and usage)

Tags: java, concurrency, queue, priority-queue

I am having some trouble grasping the idea of a concurrent queue. I understand a queue is a FIFO, or first come first serve, data structure.

Now when we add the concurrency part, which I interpret as thread safety (please let me know if that is incorrect) things get a bit fuzzy. By concurrency we mean the way various threads can add to the queue, or delete (service an item) from the queue? Is concurrency providing a sense of ordering to this operations?

I would greatly appreciate a general description of the functionality of a concurrent queue. A similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212386/concurrent-and-blocking-queue-in-java) is not as general as I hoped.

Also is there such a thing as a concurrent priority queue? What would be its usage?

Many thanks in advance, for any brief explanations or helpful links on this subject.

Answer (score 5):

The notion that a BlockingQueue offers little overhead is a bit miss leading.  Acquiring a  lock invokes pretty substantial overhead.  Alone with the context switching we are talking thousands of instructions. Not just that but the progress of one thread will directly affect another thread.  Now, its not as bad as it was years ago, but compared to non blocking, it is substantial.

BlockingQueue's use locks for mutual exclusion

ArrayBlockingQueue, LinkedBlockingQueue, PriorityBlockingQUeue: are three blocking queue's while

ConcurrentLinkedQueue, java 1.7 LinkedTransferQueue: Uses the Michael and Scott, non blocking queue algorithm.

Under moderate to low contention (which is more of a real world scenario), the non blocking queues significantly out perform blocking queues.

And to note on Steve's comment about the lack of bottlenecks.  Under heavy contention a non blocking algorithm can bottle neck on the constant cas attempts, while blocking will suspend the threads.  We then see that a BlockingQueue under heavy contention slightly out performs a non blocking queue, but that type of contention isn't a norm by any means.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by checking out the [BlockingQueue](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) interface definition as this is the cornerstone for using queues for communication between threads and contains utility methods to allow producer and consumer threads to access the queue in either a blocking or non-blocking fashion.  This, along with thread-safe access is my understanding of what constitutes a "concurrent queue" (although I've never heard of that phrase - `BlockingQueue` merely exists in the `java.util.concurrent` package).

To answer the second part of your question, the priority queue implementation you should study is [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html).  This may be useful if your producer thread(s) are producing tasks of varying priorities (e.g. requests from "normal users" and "power users") and you wish to control the order in which tasks are processed by your consumer thread(s).  One possible pitfall to avoid is the starvation of low priority tasks that are never removed from the queue due to the constant influx of higher priority tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I understand by "concurrency" that the queue is thread-safe. This does not mean that it will be efficient. However, I would imagine that the Java queue use a lock-free implementation which means that there is little or no penatly when two threads attempt a push or a pop at the same time. What generally happens is that they use atomic locking at an assembler level which ensures that the same object cannot be popped twice.

I once wrote a lock-free FIFO queue (in Delphi ) which worked very well. Much more efficient that a previous version which used Critical sections. The CS version ground to a halt especially with many threads all trying to access the queue. The lock-free version however had no bottlenecks depsite many threads accessing it a lot.

Comment: Acquiring a lock in order to modify a thread-safe Queue implementation adds little overhead and all BlockingQueue implementations within the java.util.concurrent package will use at least one lock (some use two for putting / taking).  Without locks producers / consumers are unable to perform blocking puts / takes and bulk operations (e.g. drainTo) cannot be done atomically.

Comment: I thought that Java uses lock-free queues: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving here a [link to the `java.util.concurrent` package](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) that I think contains very important information about some questions raised here.

See: Concurrent Collections and [Memory Consistency Properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility)